# deleting unnecessary characters from txt document

Tags: character, notepad++, automatic-properties

I am facing a bit of a problem, i am not good at programming yet.
i have a text that looks like this:

```
D28151373 15-04 040 028230457 01-01 015 D28250305 01-08 048 D28250661 03-01 032 028151376 12-01 057 028230460 01-01 001 D28250305 01-09 049 D28250663 03-01 025 028151377 12-01 057 028230462 01-01 014
```

just like a million times longer.

What I need to do is to delete the first character and then keep the next 11 characters (including spaces) and the delete the next 9 characters, keep 11 characters, delete 9 characters, and on and on and on...

There must be a simple way to make a script do this automaticity but I simply can't figure out how. (BTW I am good at understanding the code but I am lost when i have to start myself) and what is the best program to do this simple task in, I was thinking about Notepad++ or C++.

Comment: the line should end up looking like this: "28151373 15 28230457 01 28250305 01 28250661 03 28151376 12 28230460 01 28250305 01 28250663 03 28151377 12 28230462 01

Comment: Notepad++ it is a text editor , c++ it is a programming language

Comment: ohhh damn im even more lost, bare with me im new at this

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `.(.{11}).{8}`
- Replace with: `$1` <-- there is a space after `$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
.       : 1 character
(.{11}) : group 1, 11 characters
.{8}    : 8 characters
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1   : group 1 and a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
28151373 15 28230457 01 28250305 01 28250661 03 28151376 12 28230460 01 28250305 01 28250663 03 28151377 12 28230462 01
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a Notepad++ macro:

- Macro → Start Recording
- <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+→</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>
- Macro → Stop Recording
- Macro → Run a Macro Multiple Times...